# Error occurs while using Google Cloud Vision Face Detection API

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, google-cloud-vision

In my application, I am uploading image to get emotion response from Google Cloud Vision API. But while sending the captured image to cloud, I am getting error as

Error

```
401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=AIzaSyAbr--TMSjNERLbwHB4p6a0EnYvVaFlqus
03-08 16:30:41.588 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
03-08 16:30:41.588 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
03-08 16:30:41.588 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
03-08 16:30:41.588 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at com.emotionrecognition.CloudVision.send(CloudVision.java:81)
03-08 16:30:41.589 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at com.emotionrecognition.DetectedEmotionAnalysis$DetectEmotion.doInBackground(DetectedEmotionAnalysis.java:177)
03-08 16:30:41.589 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at com.emotionrecognition.DetectedEmotionAnalysis$DetectEmotion.doInBackground(DetectedEmotionAnalysis.java:172)
03-08 16:30:41.589 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
03-08 16:30:41.589 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
03-08 16:30:41.589 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
03-08 16:30:41.590 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
03-08 16:30:41.590 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
03-08 16:30:41.590 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
03-08 16:30:41.590 1401-1982/com.emotionrecognition D/GCV Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=AIzaSyAbr--TMSjNERLbwHB4p6a0EnYvVaFlqus
03-08 16:30:55.951 1401-1401/com.emotionrecognition V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@8a9b4a4 nm : com.emotionrecognition ic=null
03-08 16:30:55.952 1401-1401/com.emotionrecognition I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
```

This is the code i have written to send image to URL,i am not getting response from Google Cloud Vision API ,when i paste that url in web browser i am getting error as 404 file not found

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] imageByteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

            URL url = new URL(Config.CLOUD_VISION_URL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // Features JSON
            JSONObject featuresJson = new JSONObject();
            featuresJson.put("type", "FACE_DETECTION");
            featuresJson.put("maxResults", 1);

            JSONArray featuresJSONArray = new JSONArray();
            featuresJSONArray.put(featuresJson);

            // Image JSON
            JSONObject imageJson = new JSONObject();
            imageJson.put("content", encodedImageString);

            // Requests JSON
            JSONObject requestsJson = new JSONObject();
            requestsJson.put("image", imageJson);
            requestsJson.put("features", featuresJSONArray);

            JSONArray requestsJSONArray = new JSONArray();
            requestsJSONArray.put(requestsJson);

            JSONObject wholeRequest = new JSONObject();
            wholeRequest.put("requests", requestsJSONArray);

            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            out.write(wholeRequest.toString());

            out.flush();
            out.close();

            int response_code = con.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("GCV Response Code", ""+response_code);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            String temp;
            while((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
            String response = sb.toString();

            JSONObject responseJSONObject = new JSONObject(response);

            if (response_code == 200) {
                Log.d("GCV", "Successful response");
            }

            JSONArray responsesArray = responseJSONObject.getJSONArray("responses");
            JSONObject faceAnnotationsJson = responsesArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject annotedEmotionsJson = faceAnnotationsJson.getJSONArray("faceAnnotations").getJSONObject(0);
            return annotedEmotionsJson;
```

Comment: It says that it can't find the image that you uploaded

Comment: Images are successfully uploaded, but when i print cloud vision url in chrome getting 404 error

Comment: [link](https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate)

Comment: Can you show us some code you're working on in the question to inspect this further?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot print cloud vision url in chrome as it needs your credentials to access.

You can either access cloud vision url using api_key or OATH2.0 service account

Either way you do, you need to provide those credentials in your post requests.

Another thing is that you need to make sure your image url is accessible by Vision API.

Either your image url is an public http url, or it is a GCS url with is either public or can be accessed by your credential.

Or you can send image bytes directly.

It seems to me that you are using API_KEY instead of OATH2.0 credentials

401-1982/com.emotionrecognition W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=AIzaSyAbr--TMSjNERLbwHB4p6a0EnYvVaFlqus

Are you uploading image to your private GCS bucket? If that is true I suggest you mark your image as public image and try again.

As far as I know api_key cannot be used to access private GCS bucket.

And it is not recommended to paste your api_key directly, you may want to remove that key you use.